# python pandas: merge two data frame but didn't merge the repeat rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

I have two dataframe: df1 and df2.

df1 is following:

```
    name  exist
     a      1
     b      1
     c      1
     d      1
     e      1
```

df2 (just have one column:name)is following:

```
     name  
      e      
      f      
      g      
      a     
      h
```

I want to merge these two dataframe, and didn't merge repeat names, I mean, if the name in df2 exist in df1, just show one time, else if the name is df2 not exist in df1, set the exist value is 0 or Nan. for example as df1(there is a and e), and df2(there is a and e, just showed a, e one time), I want to be the following df:

```
     a      1
     b      1
     c      1
     d      1
     e      1
     f      0 
     g      0
     h      0
```

I used the concat function to do it, my code is following:

```
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                'exist': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'a']})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
print(df)
```

but the result is wrong(name a and e is repeated to be showed):

```
  exist name
 0     1    a
 1     1    b 
 2     1    c
 3     1    d
 4     1    e
 0   NaN    e
 1   NaN    f
 2   NaN    g
 3   NaN    h
 4   NaN    a
```

please give your hands, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by your title, you can use `merge` instead of `concat` and specify `how` parameter as `outer` since you want to keep all records from `df1` and `df2` which defines an outer join:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'name', how = 'outer').fillna(0)

# exist name
# 0   1    a
# 1   1    b
# 2   1    c
# 3   1    d
# 4   1    e
# 5   0    f
# 6   0    g
# 7   0    h
```

Comment: thanks @Psidom for your answer, I will accept it. Could you tell me the meaning of  how = 'outer' in detail, I mean the difference of left, right, inner, butter. Thanks!

Comment: Check this http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html and also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448023/what-is-the-difference-between-left-right-outer-and-inner-joins. Roughly, a join is a kind of match of tables based on some key columns; left keeps all records from the first data frame; right keeps all records from the second data frame; inner keeps only records that exists in both data frames and outer keeps all records.

Comment: @tktktk0711, here is a visual guide to what is happening with DataFrame `merge` https://youtu.be/9d5-Ti6onew?t=13m7s